# Excluding specfic columns in Pandas for column based computations

Tags: pandas, mean

```
Year A B C D
1900 1 2 3 4
1901 2 3 4 5
```

I have  a dataset which aligns with the  above format.

When i want to perform calculations on column values the year is getting added to the column values and distorting the result. For example

```
df['mean'] = df.mean(axis='columns')
```

In the above example i just want to exclude year from calculations. I have 100 plus columns in my data frame and i cannot manually use each of the columns . 'year' is also the Index for my dataframe

Comment: Why not either drop or set index the year column first: `df.set_index('Year').mean(axis='columns')` ? , if year is already the index, it wouldnt get calculated in the mean

Comment: I realized the problem and solution 

'df.set_index(['Year']
df['mean'] = df.mean(axis='columns')'

This did not work

But when i added inplace = True , it worked. 

'df.set_index(['Year'],inplace = True)'

Answer (score 0):

I realized the problem and solution

```
   df.set_index(['Year']
    df['mean'] = df.mean(axis='columns')
```

This did not work

But when i added inplace = True , it worked.

```
'df.set_index(['Year'],inplace = True)' 
  df['mean'] = df.mean(axis='columns')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also drop the year column and create a new dataframe and after applying the mean to individual columns we can add the year column.

```
df2 = df.drop('Year')
df2['Mean']=df.mean(axis='columns')
df2.concat(df.Year,df2)
```